# Formula to select the name associated with lowest value from data set & a random name from the lowest options if tied

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-query, microsoft-excel

In Google Sheets, I have 4 Names associated with 4 data points that update throughout the month. I'd like to auto pick the name associated with the lowest data point. If there are 2, 3 or all 4 that have the same lowest point, I'd then like to select a random name but only from the lowest data points.

Ex Scenario 1 - The formula should select adam from the list.

```
Adam - 2
Bill - 3
Charlie - 4
David - 4
```

Ex Scenario 2 - The formula should select a random name from the adam, charlie & david only.

```
Adam - 2
Bill - 3
Charlie - 2
David - 2
```

Ex Scenario 3 - The formula should select a random name from the adam & bill only.

```
Adam - 1
Bill - 1
Charlie - 2
David - 2
```

Any help in developing a formula would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Hi, welcome to WebApps. Would you please summarise your research (as mentioned in [How to Ask](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)) as well as any work that you did to try and solve this yourself. Would you also describe EXACTLY what is the question - you've described a broad scenario but not a specific problem that you are having. Would you also please provide a sample of your data in table format (is the data in ne cell per row, or two cells per row, as well as an example of how you expect a successful outcome to be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

For the solution you could use a long formula in a single cell or 2 much more understandable formulas in 2 different cells.
The solution I propose works for any number of names, not just 4.
Assuming the names are in column `A2:A` and the scores are in column `B2:B`, this is the long formula:

```
=if(
COUNTA(Filter(A2:A,B2:B=min(B2:B)))=1,Filter(A2:A,B2:B=min(B2:B)),
INDEX(Filter(A2:A,B2:B=min(B2:B)),RANDBETWEEN(1, COUNTA(Filter(A2:A,B2:B=min(B2:B)))))
)
```

As you can see the formula could be simplified if we used another cell with the formula:

```
=Filter(A2:A,B2:B=min(B2:B))
```

If the latter were put in cell `F2`, the solution would be given by the formula:

```
=if(COUNTA(F2:F)=1,F2:F,INDEX(F2:F,RANDBETWEEN(1, COUNTA(F2:F))))
```

Comment: Thank you Daniele! This is wonderful and so very much appreciated!